# CGI scripts: when can you return a document, instead of an HTTP response?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php, cgi

Script 1 below is bash, and is at `https://example.com/cgi-bin/test`. It produces the output 'Under construction' when fetched. It echos `Status` and `Content-type` headers, and some HTML. If I instead try to echo an entire HTML doc Apache just complains about an invalid header.

Script 2 below is php, and is at `https://example.com/cgi-bin/test2.php`. Unlike the bash script, this one returns an HTML document.

How is it that script 2 can send an entire HTML doc, but script 1 can't?

*Script 1*

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<'EOF'
Status: 200 OK
Content-type: text/html

<p>Under construction.</p>
EOF
```

*Script 2*

```
<?php
print <<<EOF  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...etc
  </head>

  <body>
  ...etc
  </body>
</html>
EOF;
?>
```

**EDIT**

`php` comes in 2 flavours: the CLI and CGI versions. If you just run Script 2 from the command line as `php test2.php` then the *only* output produced by `php` is exactly what you see: the HTML doc. `php-cgi` is the CGI version (install on Ubuntu/Deb as `apt install php-cgi`). Apache (effectively) runs the CGI version (in real life, it does this slightly differently, but with the same results):

```
 $ php-cgi test2.php
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
...rest of doc
```

CGI scripts have to return at least `Content-type` to Apache (but can return more headers, including `Status`). So the answer is that *both* scripts work because Script 1 explicitly returns `Content-type`, while the under-the-hood CGI version of `php` does the same.

The bash script can return the entire HTML document, as long as it also returns the `Content-type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CGI you need to send the Content-Type. PHP generate it for you. (check the output via a browser, you will see it even if you dont see it in your code.

I have a CGI that I did in C, and you realy need the content-type;

In my case for exemple;

*printf("Content-Type: text/html;charset=us-ascii\n\n");*

If you need to change the header in php you have to call header at the start of your script.

ie;

*header('Content-Type: application/json');*

Comment: This is basically correct, so I've accepted it, but see my edit for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and CGI is two different things in this context.

CGI is a interface between a program - in this case a bash script - and the web server. This interface specifies communication between the web server and the program.

This standard requires that the program returns *all* headers, including status headers, before the actual content. In HTTP, headers and body is separated by a single line - thus the format where you have

```
Header
Header

Content
```

After the headers, you're free to include a full HTML document - or any other kind of data matching the headers you send.

PHP makes a few assumptions for you, and unless you override it, it sets content type, status code and so forth automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a valid CGI header response, not an HTTP response, if calling a script via CGI through Apache. I think in essence (detail below) you need to remove "Status: 200 OK" from your file, and it might work.

There is a good article by Apache themselves (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html) which shows you the minimum to achive a valid response.

An example header received by the client might be as follows:

```
HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2021 19:58:00 GMT
Server: My_Bash_Script
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: My_Bash_Script
Pragma: public
Expires: Tue, 06 Dec 2021 20:58:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public
Last-Modified: Tue, 06 Dec 2021 20:58:00 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie, User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Under construction</title>
<body><p>Under construction.</p></body>
</html>
```

But your CGI, only needs to send from "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" down.

A rather good article can be found here explaining the headers:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039

With regards to a served PHP file via Apache, there are several layers of communication:

- A request is made of Apache on a TCP port. This includes a request header if via HTTP.
- Apache runs any rules (e.g. mod_rewrite) and handles any SSL connections / handshakes required.
- Apache then detects the file extension as PHP and calls the PHP script through the PHP interpreter.
- The PHP code is interpreted, and turned into a static string (hopefully :-) which is returned to Apache and contains the HTML code.
- Apache then adds the header information to the HTML page, along with any other outbound processing.
- This is serialised and piped back over the TCP connection to the client.

Another good way to explore the headers is to use Firefox / Chrome Developer Tools (pressing F12 in Firefox opens them). Goto the Network Tab once Developer Tools are open and reload the page (Ctrl + R on Windows/Linux). There is a "Raw" option where you can see the exact data that was send and received.

Finally, if you find a website, or even that your CGI is being served over http rather than https, you can install Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org) and easily monitor the traffic conversations to learn the differential between what you are sending that is being misunderstood and what a normal static html page conversatin looks like served by Apache.

P.S. (In 2022,) If you are indeed running Apache 2.2:

- You maybe missing out on other features in Apache2.4 which may help you get to where you want to be a bit quicker: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/new_features_2_4.html
- And please note that Apache 2.2 is EOL (since 2017), and contains a number of vulnerabilities: https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_22.html

Comment: Sorry, think you might have misunderstood. *Both* scripts already work, and I've got a bucket load of C++ that does exactly the same as the bash script. My problem was understanding how the php also manages to work. The other 2 answers indicate that php *does* actually return the 'missing' headers to Apache, which makes sense. I'll check later.